# How to find a maximum matching in this graph

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Let's consider this graph:

[image]

Now I take a matching M that only contains the edge 1. Clearly this matching is not maximum, because I can take the edge 3, so given that:

> We can easily notice that if there exists an augmenting path p with
>   respect to M, then M is not maximum.

I should find an augmenting path w.r.t M. Looking at the definition for a matching M:

> An augmenting path is an alternating path that starts from and ends on
>   free vertices.

and

> an alternating path is a path in which the edges belong alternatively
>   to the matching and not to the matching,

What I don't get is how to build such a path given my matching? My only possibilites are:

- start from the top vertex of the edge 2
- start from the right vertex of the edge 5
- start from the bottom vertex of the edge 4

Now from there I take the edge 2 or 4 or 5, then I take the edge 1 and then I cannot go further.

So is the first quote a one-way implication (so if M is not a maximum matching then I don't always find an augmenting path)? Or did I misunderstood how to build my augmenting path?

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm you're looking for is called the Hungarian Maximum Matching Algorithm, and it works for any bipartite graph, for which it always gives the largest-size matching. More detailed info can be found on [this Wolfram MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HungarianMaximumMatchingAlgorithm.html) and [this link](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheHungarianMaximumMatchingAlgorithm/) has a neat visualisation of how the algorithm works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are 4 maximal matchings:{3,1}, {3,4}, {3,5}, {2}. They're matchings, since they do not share any vertices, and they're maximal since by adding any additional edge (to any of those four) necessitates the existence of a shared vertex, thereby rendering them as non-matchings.

Comment: I know how to find the maximum matchings in this graph. My question is, given the matching I started with, which I know that it's not a maximum matching, how can I find an augmenting path w.r.t this matching? Sorry maybe the title of the question is a bit misleading but I think it's enough clear in the body ;)

Comment: Ah, indeed! Let's see.

Comment: A path is a sequence of edges that connects the vertices, so I'm not sure 3,1,4 and 3,1,5 are paths since the vertices from 3 are not connected with the one from 1-4 or 1-5.

Comment: I think I got it. I think the trick is in the fact that you traverse 1 back and forth in one alternation. This is an undirected graph so given an edge with vertices a and b the edge is just {a,b}, no? Unlike in a directed graph where they would be distinct, i.e. (a,b) or (b,a). So the trick is that you go up the edge 1 and down again BUT that counts as a single alternation. I hope that was clear? So the augmented path starts with edge 2, then 1(going up), then 1(going back down), and then edge 4 (or 5 for another path).

Comment: But 2-1-5 and 2-1-4 are not paths. The vertices need to be distincts (except the first and the last and then you get a cycle)... If I follow the vertices from your "path", I get two times on the bottom vertice of the edge 1 and that is not my starting/end point so it's not a path.

Comment: See section 1.2 M-alternating trees http://www.win.tue.nl/~nikhil/courses/2012/2WO08/vondrak-matching-nonbipartite.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you have the matching formed from just edge 1, then edge 3 by itself is an augmenting path:

- its endpoints are unmatched, and
- the edges (vacuously) alternate between matched and unmatched edges.

There’s no requirement in an alternating path that the path actually use both matched and unmatched edges.

Once you’ve found that augmenting path, you can then add edge 3 into your matching to produce a larger matching.